# Getting Reader Undefined error while loading JSON data into combobox in EXTJS

Tags: json, extjs

I have two dropdowns, on changing the value of one dropdown it should populate value in another dropdown. I am making ajax call using JSON and I am getting response as well. But after getting response, values not getting loaded into store of second combo box. Getting error: Reader undefined
Below is my code:

//Second COMBO Description

```
  var AGENT_NAME_Field = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    id: 'AGENT_NAME',
    name: 'AGENT_NAME',       
    width: 300,
    displayField: 'name',
    store: agentNameStore,
    queryMode: 'local',
    allowBlank: false,
    listConfig: {
        getInnerTpl: function() {
            return '<div data-qtip="{name}">{name}</div>';
        }
    }
});
```

// Store for second combo

```
 var agentNameStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url : 'name.json',
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        totalProperty: 'results',
        root:'items'
    }, [{name: 'name'}, {name: 'name'}])

}

});
```

// This is how I am making ajax call and FUNCTION_NAME_Field is first combo

```
 FUNCTION_NAME_Field.on('select', function() {
    AGENT_NAME_Field.reset();
    agentNameStore.proxy= new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: '/omsWeb/navigation/getAgent.htm?id='+FUNCTION_NAME_Field.getValue()});
    agentNameStore.load();
});
```

I traced the logs, I am getting the response as success but after that its throwing error: Reader undefined.
Am I missing something? Or is something wrong? Could anyone please help.
Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. remove this string:

   ```
   agentNameStore.proxy= new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url: '/omsWeb/navigation/getAgent.htm?id='+FUNCTION_NAME_Field.getValue()});
   ```
2. and replace url value in proxy of your store:

   ```
   url: '/omsWeb/navigation/getAgent.htm?id='+ Ext.ComponentManager.get(ID).getValue()}
   ```

where **ID** is id of FUNCTION_NAME_Field

**Edited:**

Check this example i created for you

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

  var ds = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      pageSize: 10,
      proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/topics-remote.php',
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          root: 'topics',
          totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
      },

      fields: [
        {name: 'id', mapping: 'post_id'},
        {name: 'title', mapping: 'topic_title'},
        {name: 'topicId', mapping: 'topic_id'},
        {name: 'author', mapping: 'author'},
        {name: 'lastPost', mapping: 'post_time', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'timestamp'},
        {name: 'excerpt', mapping: 'post_text'}
      ]
  });

  var ds2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      pageSize: 10,
      fields: [
        {name: 'id', mapping: 'id'},
      ]
  });

  var cb1 = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
      id: 'cb1',
      fieldLabel: 'TEST',
      store: ds,
      displayField: 'title',
      valueField: 'id',
      multiSelect: false,
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });

  var cb2 = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
      disabled : true,
      id: 'cb2',
      fieldLabel: 'TEST2',
      store: ds2,
      displayField: 'title',
      valueField: 'id',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
  });

  cb1.on('select', function(combo, value) {
      cb2.enable();       
      ds2.load();     
  });

  ds2.on('beforeload', function(store, operation) {
      alert(Ext.ComponentManager.get('cb1').getValue());
      this.setProxy(Ext.create('Ext.data.proxy.Ajax', {
            url : '/omsWeb/navigation/getAgent.htm',
            extraParams : {
                id: Ext.ComponentManager.get('cb1').getValue()
            }
          }));
  },ds2);
})
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your solution. Now I am getting the error:this.model is undefined. Could you please help?

Comment: Try to add `model:` to your `proxy: {` example here: 
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/docs/index.html#/api/Ext.data.Model

Comment: The model for store was not defined. So it was giving error. But here FUNCTION_NAME_Field value is coming undefined. Because I think the store code is preloaded and by that time there is no data selected in the combo box. You have any solution for this?

Comment: May be better to create component inside  `FUNCTION_NAME_Field.on('select', function() {`.

Comment: Hi, I am not clear what you are saying. When I posted the original code I was trying to do the same. But I was getting Reader undefined error. Please refer my original code posted and let me know what should I do?

Comment: In your original code you reset proxy and it leads to reader == null. And all of your code (store creation and ombobox creation) inside `FUNCTION_NAME_Field.on('select', function() {`

Comment: But combobox creation cannot be done onchange because it should exist before as well.. Any other way?

Comment: FUNCTION_NAME_Field != AGENT_NAME_Field. Or you want to reload combobox store after combobox item select?

Comment: Yes I want to reload second dropdown based on the value of first dropdown. Here how can I define second dropdown inside FUNCTION_NAME_Field.on('select', function() {

Comment: Because AGENT_NAME_Field is a dropdown which should be viewable empty before on change of first dropdown. Other way I defined only proxy and reader inside the onchange function and rest of the code is outise. But here I am getting error: this.model undefined... I dont know how to define model for store in this function. Please help

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the code. I will modify my code accordingly and get back to you soon

Comment: Hi, I tried this code  it is making call and getting response, but data is not loaded into dropdown. Also ajax call is happening only once at the first time click on the combo 2.

Comment: just replace code that maintain `select` (check my answer update) and you'll ds2 will be updated each time you select cb1.

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining your proxy without including a reader definition.  Not sure why you are even doing that to begin with -- each combo should already have its own preconfigured store+proxy+reader.  I'm not sure why you're changing it on the fly.

Comment: On the fly I have to load the dropdown with data. I dont know how to achieve it. Please post the code if you can.Thanks